# How to change address of c# struct manually?

Tags: c#, pointers, fortran

What I want to do is directly connect to Fortran common block variables from c# code.
The original code comes from [here](https://www.luckingtechnotes.com/calling-fortran-dll-from-csharp/).

I modified the code a little bit and tried to connect directly to Fortran common block from c# as in the attached code.

MyLib.f90

```
module MyLib

    implicit none

    type, bind(c) :: PointType
        integer :: Id
        real(8) :: Coords(3)
    end type
    integer :: Int1, Int2
    real(8) :: Dble1
    common/COM1/ Int1, Int2, Dble1

    integer, parameter :: LEN_PATH = 256

contains

    subroutine TranslateViaArrays(delta, n, coords)

        !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: TranslateViaArrays
        !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'TranslateViaArrays' :: TranslateViaArrays

        real(8), intent(in) :: delta(3)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        real(8), intent(inout) :: coords(3,n)

        integer :: i

        do i = 1, n
            coords(:,i) = coords(:,i) + delta(:)
        end do

    end subroutine

    subroutine TranslateViaTypes(delta, n, points)

        !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: TranslateViaTypes
        !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'TranslateViaTypes' :: TranslateViaTypes

        real(8), intent(in) :: delta(3)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        type(PointType), intent(inout), target :: points(n)

        integer :: i, words
        type(PointType), pointer :: point

        inquire(iolength=words) point
        print *, words ! Confirm the size of PointType. Id(1) + Pad(1) + Coords(3*2) = 8 words. 1 word = 4 bytes.

        do i = 1, n
            point => points(i) ! Use a local (pointer) variable to avoid writing points(i) multiple times.
            point%Coords(:) = point%Coords(:) + delta(:)
        end do

    end subroutine

    subroutine TranslateViaInputFile(inputPath)

        !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES DLLEXPORT :: TranslateViaInputFile
        !DIR$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS: 'TranslateViaInputFile' :: TranslateViaInputFile

        character(len=LEN_PATH), intent(in) :: inputPath

        print *, "Input File: " // trim(inputPath)

        ! Do something amazing....
        Int1 = -10
        Int2 = 1250
        Dble1 = 123.5

    end subroutine

end module
```

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpApp
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    static class Program
    {
        private static string ToHex(this int value)
        {
            return String.Format("0x{0:X}", value);
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Program myProcInfo = new Program();
            FComm cStruct = new FComm(0, 0, 0);

            IntPtr iAddr = new IntPtr(0);
            int ComAddr = 0x000073e0;

            try
            {
                RunTranslateViaArrays();
                RunTranslateViaTypes();
                RunTranslateViaInputFile();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }

            //iAddr = myProcInfo.ProcInfo();
            iAddr = ProcInfo();

            int numInt = iAddr.ToInt32() + ComAddr;
            IntPtr pVal = (IntPtr)numInt;
            int Val;

            Val = Marshal.ReadInt16(pVal);
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(FComm));
            FComm cStr1 = (FComm)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pVal, typeof(FComm));
            Console.WriteLine("=========================\t{0}\n", Val);
            //Console.WriteLine("==========\t{0:x}\n",*cStr1);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(cStr1, pVal, false);
            cStr1.Dble1 = 12.5;
            string hexAddr = numInt.ToHex();
            unsafe
            {
                //int* cInt1;
                //cInt1 = numInt;
            }
            RunTranslateViaInputFile();
        }

        private static void RunTranslateViaArrays()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Translate Via Arrays");

            var delta = new[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
            int n = 10;
            var coords = new double[n, 3]; // Note that the indices are reversed from Fortran.
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                coords[i, 0] = i;
                coords[i, 1] = i + 1;
                coords[i, 2] = -i;
            }

            FortranLib.TranslateViaArrays(delta, ref n, coords);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                Console.WriteLine("Point {0}: ({1}, {2}, {3})", i + 1, coords[i, 0], coords[i, 1], coords[i, 2]);

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static void RunTranslateViaTypes()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Translate Via Types");

            var delta = new[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
            int n = 10;
            var points = new Point[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                points[i] = new Point(id: i + 1, x: i, y: i + 1, z: -i);

            FortranLib.TranslateViaTypes(delta, ref n, points);

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                var point = points[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Point {0}: ({1}, {2}, {3})", point.Id, point.Coords[0], point.Coords[1], point.Coords[2]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        private static void RunTranslateViaInputFile()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Translate Via Input File");

            const string inputPath = @"C:\temp\input.txt";

            // Convert string to Fortran array of characters.
            char[] inputPathChars = inputPath.ToCharacterArrayFortran(FortranLib.PathLength);

            FortranLib.TranslateViaInputFile(inputPathChars);
        }

        private static IntPtr ProcInfo()
        {
            IntPtr FortBaseAddr = new IntPtr(0);
            //Process myProcess = new Process();
            //ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
            //myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
            Process myProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

            //myProcess.Start();

            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            ProcessModule myProcessModule;

            // Get all the modules associated with 'myProcess'.
            ProcessModuleCollection myProcessModuleCollection = myProcess.Modules;

            Console.WriteLine("Base addresses of the modules associated "
                + "with 'current process' are:");
            // Display the 'BaseAddress' of each of the modules.
            for (int i = 0; i < myProcessModuleCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                myProcessModule = myProcessModuleCollection[i];
                //Console.WriteLine(myProcessModule.ModuleName + " : "
                //    + myProcessModule.BaseAddress);
                if (myProcessModule.ModuleName == "FortranLib.dll")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FortranLib found");
                    FortBaseAddr = myProcessModule.BaseAddress;
                    //return myProcessModule.BaseAddress;
                }
            }

            // Get the main module associated with 'myProcess'.
            myProcessModule = myProcess.MainModule;
            // Display the 'BaseAddress' of the main module.
            Console.WriteLine("The process's main module's base address is: "
                + myProcessModule.BaseAddress);
            //myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
            return FortBaseAddr;
        }
    }
}
```

I generated map file and found ComAddr of COMMON block.
What I really want to do is overwrite cStr1's address to COMMON block in Fortran.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look at `P/Invoke`.  It provides a mechanism for calling into non-.NET code.  Then, on the Fortran side, see what the exported names of Fortran functions are (for example, how would you call them from, say, a `C` program).  Finally, find out how you would expose that struct through a function call.  Combine those three things together and you will likely have a solution.

Comment: Also have a look at unsafe code and pointers https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/unsafe-code Your common block may be at a fixed point in memory so you could have an unsafe pointer to it.